# jQuery check if a form has any elements with a data attribute of data-val

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to detect if any elements within a form have a data attribute called `data-val`.

If they do then run the function enclosed in the if statement. I've tried this:

```
            var checkValidation = $('.uiModalContent').closest('form').find('input[data-val="true"], textarea[data-val="true"]');

            if(checkValidation.length > 0) {

                $.validator.unobtrusive.parseDynamicContent('.uiModalContent');

            }
```

However it does not work as expected probably because the checkValidation becomes an array and checking using length is also probably not the best way of doing this.

Can anyone offer fixes / alternate solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [has attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

```
'[data-val]'
```

I.E.:

```
$('input[data-val], textarea[data-val], select[data-val]').chain().stuff();
```

Using `[data-val="true"]` would mean that the value of `[data-val]` is `"true"`, such as:

```
<element data-val="true" />
```

---

```
var $elems;
$elems = $('.uiModalContent').closest('form').find('[data-val]');
if ($elemens.length) {
  doSomething();
}
```

Comment: How would I run that function if an element is found within the form that has that attribute?

Comment: Still not sure how I would run that function if that attribute is found

Comment: No my question was how to run the function if I find those attributes. Which is what my original code did but it caused issues because of it being an array.

Comment: @Cameron, jQuery functions return `jQuery.init` objects which are Array-like. `$.validator...` is not native to jQuery, so you're going to have to update your question with more information if you want a better answer. Please don't expect people to be telepathic. Take some time to read the [faq] again, especially the part about [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I use this in my form valiation:

```
// CHECK REQUIRED
$.fn.required = function(){
    return $(this).data('required') == '';
}
```

It returns true or false, you could return the value. Use it like this:

```
var required = $('input').required();
if( required ) // Do something
```

So in your case change required to val

```
<input data-val="value">
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   var boolFlag=false;
    $('.uiModalContent').closest('form')
    .find('input, textarea').filter(function(){  
      $.each($(this),function(k,v){
        if($(v).data('val')) boolFlag=true;            
        });
    });

    if(boolFlag) {   
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parseDynamicContent('.uiModalContent');

     }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JHreW/15/